# How to change the position of a single column in Python Polars library?

Tags: python, python-polars

I am working with the Python Polars library for data manipulation on a DataFrame, and I am trying to change the position of a single column. I would like to move a specific column to a different index while keeping the other columns in their respective positions.

One way of doing that is using `select`, but that requires giving a complete order for all the columns which I don't want to do.

```py
import polars as pl

# Create a simple DataFrame
data = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9],
    'D': [10, 11, 12]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to move column 'C' to index 1, so the desired output should be:

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ A   │ C   │ B   │ D    │
│ --- │ --- │ --- │ ---- │
│ i64 │ i64 │ i64 │ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   │ 7   │ 4   │ 10   │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼──────┤
│ 2   │ 8   │ 5   │ 11   │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼──────┤
│ 3   │ 9   │ 6   │ 12   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Can you name `A` along with `C`, or do you need to only use `C`?

Comment: @jqurious, not sure I understand your question.

Comment: If you were able to name the first 2 columns e.g. `.select("A", "C", pl.exclude("A", "C"))` - or if you only wanted to use `C` in the expression - you can just use `df.columns[0]` instead though.

Comment: I see. I wanted to report all columns, just with a different order. Your answer did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some attempts:

```
df.drop("C").insert_at_idx(1, df.get_column("C"))
```

```
df.select(df.columns[0], "C", pl.exclude(df.columns[0], "C"))
```

```
cols = df.columns
cols[1], cols[2] = cols[2], cols[1]
# cols[1:3] = cols[2:0:-1]

df.select(cols)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ C   ┆ B   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 7   ┆ 4   ┆ 10  │
│ 2   ┆ 8   ┆ 5   ┆ 11  │
│ 3   ┆ 9   ┆ 6   ┆ 12  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really boils down to a list mangling problem.

You can create this function

```
def reorder(df, new_position, col_name):
    neworder=df.columns
    neworder.remove(col_name)
    neworder.insert(new_position,col_name)
    return df.select(neworder)
```

then just do `reorder(df, 1, 'C')` or `df=reorder(df, 1, 'C')`

You can even make it a DataFrame method like this:

```
def reorder(self, new_position, col_name):
    neworder=self.columns
    neworder.remove(col_name)
    neworder.insert(new_position,col_name)
    return self.select(neworder)
pl.DataFrame.reorder=reorder
del reorder
```

then you can just do `df.reorder(1,'C')`